# Unable to get list of installed Simulator runtimes

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

I am using macOS and I am installing flutter. When I run to 'flutter doctor' I take a error like

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on macOS 13.6 22G120 darwin-arm64, locale
    tr-TR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    ✗ Unable to get list of installed Simulator runtimes.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

I don't know why. What is the source of this error?

Comment: It might be helpful if you include your operating system

Comment: I am using macOS. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the version of macOS. Since you're using XCode, it's assumed you're on macOS.

Answer (score 53):

I had the same issue when running updates to my flutter install. My problem turned out to be that my iOS simulator seemed to have lost all the iOS runtimes. By re-installing them my issue was resolved. This might help you, try run this via the terminal:

```
xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS
```

Comment: Yes it works. Because I deleted the iOS simulator file before.

Comment: This helped me as well.

Answer (score 10):

The above answer didn't help, but this did:

Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators -> + -> OS Version -> Download more simulator runtimes

There, first I deleted the existing iOS 17 files, and then downloaded them again.

Answer (score 4):

Open Xcode and go to the Platforms tab in Settings. There should be buttons to download any missing simulators.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. It can be easily fixed by downloading the iOS simulations on Xcode.

Follow the steps below:

- Open **Xcode** on your system (mine is a Mac) and click **Settings...**

[image]

- Go to **Platforms** tab above and verify if you have iOS installed. If it is not installed, then click the **Get** button next to it and it will be downloaded.

[image]

- In order to verify, open **Simulator** as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

- You should now be having iOS here.

[image]

This will fix the issue.

Comment: This is exactly the same answer given [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77256437/1255289) months previous.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Xcode on your system and click Settings.
2. Go to Platforms tab above and verify if you have iOS installed. If it is not installed, then click the Get button next to it and it will be downloaded.
3. In order to verify, open Simulator as shown in the screenshot below.
4. You should now be having iOS here.